# how to use field type - 'dummy' in openerp7

Tags: field, odoo

I use openERP7 and find a new type: 'dummy' in product.py

I can't find it in the documentation.

Can anyone please explain to me with examples?

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**'field_name':fields.dummy(type='',string='',relation='')**

relation will be used if type is many2one.
then relation will be related class.

Comment: please explain the exact use of dummy fields in openerp